# order by count query in cassandra

Tags: group-by, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am trying to execute this query in CQL

```
select path_name, count(*) as cont from a_data where a_id=5 group by path_name order by cont limit 10;
```

And getting following error :

> InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
>   message="Undefined column name cont"

If I execute similar query in psql it works fine, why doesn't cassandra support it ? Can someone help ?

CQL version info :

> cqlsh> show version [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 |
>   Native protocol v4]

Comment: Because Cassandra reads sequentially, and can only order result sets by their on-disk sort order.  You cannot order result sets in Cassandra by computed or even arbitrary columns.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the explanation. It's very hard to find whether this is supported, in the Cassandra docs. Or may be it's because I am a NOSQL newbie.